# How can I auto-share anything sent to one Drive account with another?

Tags: hard-drive, file-sharing, google-docs

People sometimes share Docs with my rarely used Google account. So I have to email them and ask them to use my main Google account instead.

It's a hassle for them and for me, plus it slows down our work.

Is there a way to automatically share any Doc that's in my rarely-used account with my main account?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly auto forwarding email from a less used account to your main account may be what you are looking for? [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en) is Googles guide to auto forwarding.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not about email, but about docs in my Drive. People share does with one of my less used Google accounts and I have to keep asking them to share the docs with my main account.